# stucked in finding content of one column from one data-frame into the another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My initial dataframe looks like

```
    id     name     status     
 
 HV200     john     Present
 HV300     harry    Absent
 HV400     peter    Present
```

Other Dataframe is

```
id     name     status     
 
 HV200     john     Present
 HV200     john     Absent
 HV300     harry    Absent
 HV400     peter    Present
 HV500     steven   Absent
 HV300     harry    Present
```

I want to extract all the **id** present in Table from the **Table 2**(With duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Set here

```
result = set(table2['id']) & set(table1['id'])
```

the above will return a `set` you can convert it back into a list like so

```
list(result)
```

here `table1` and `table2` are your DataFrames

Comment: Hey , i solved it using this code  :  Table_2[Table_2['id'].isin(Table_1['id'])]